# Prevent pgbouncer from logging to syslog on Centos 7

Tags: rsyslog, pgbouncer

Stock installation of pgbouncer on centos 7. It logs connections/stats/etc to both /var/log/messages as well as /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log. How do I stop it from logging to /var/log/messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a blocklist for syslog

it might be on a location like `/etc/rsyslog.d/01-blocklist.conf`

just add something like

`:msg,contains,"whatever pgbouncer is doing" ~`

The `~` operator means it will discard the message

you can also use regex just check the docs:
http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html

Comment: Rsyslog may print a warning like "warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead" ---- because of using legacy mode in above example. https://selivan.github.io/2017/02/07/rsyslog-log-forward-save-filename-handle-multi-line-failover.html explains how STOP statement could be used.

Comment: `:syslogtag, isequal, "pgbouncer:" ~` may be better and simple compared to filtering out specific messages using "contains".